# Apply offset to column on the right - Ionic grid

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

I am building an hybrid-app with `ionic` and I am trying to build a grid with two columns with `width: 25%`. This is the snippet with my code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-offset-25 col-25">1</div>
  <div class="col col-25">2</div>
  <div class="col col-25"> <!-- Empty --> </div>
</div>
```

The structure is working, but I have to use an empty column to get the result. Is it possible to apply `col-offset-25` on the right of the second `<div>` tag?

Comment: This might help you: http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-create-complex-layouts-in-ionic/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the third column you should get what you are looking for (if I understand you intention right)

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col col-offset-25 col-25">1</div>
  <div class="col col-25">2</div>
</div>
```

The first column will have offset 25%, take 25% if the width. The second column will be the next and will also 25% of the width. And after that there will be 25% gap

Comment: I tried but apparently, if I don't remove it the column size gets equal to 33%